# Pipeline configuration in HERE OLP

Tags: pipeline, here-olp

I configured a new pipeline in HERE OLP. Having issues while running it. If anybody has past experience dealing with here olp pipeline, please advise.

```
2019-08-16 18:21:00.946 [SIGTERM handler] level=ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend  - RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM // PipeLineId=63e07977-ba0a-4997-a633-1b578ae86ce1 Realm=olp-ford DeploymentId=4832de82-afb9-4f03-b92a-a6ba12eb9116 VersionId=0bc6df20-8873-4195-bfdb-87271a95fdba
3-4195-bfdb-87271a95fdba
com.here.platform.data.processing.exception.ContextRuntimeException:  // Task=seedmap cat=highways l=adas-attributes p=18939748
    at com.here.platform.data.processing.exception.ContextRuntimeException$.apply(ContextRuntimeException.scala:46)
    at com.here.platform.data.processing.exception.package$.wrapInTryWithContext(package.scala:109)
    at com.here.platform.data.processing.driver.impl.executors.DirectCompileFnUtils$$anonfun$applyMappingFn$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(DirectCompileFnUtils.scala:83)
    at com.here.platform.data.processing.driver.impl.executors.DirectCompileFnUtils$$anonfun$applyMappingFn$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(DirectCompileFnUtils.scala:82)
    at com.here.platform.data.processing.logging.Implicits$LogContextKeyWrapper$.withChild$extension(Implicits.scala:46)
    at com.here.platform.data.processing.driver.impl.executors.DirectCompileFnUtils$$anonfun$applyMappingFn$1.apply(DirectCompileFnUtils.scala:82)
    at com.here.platform.data.processing.driver.impl.executors.DirectCompileFnUtils$$anonfun$applyMappingFn$1.apply(DirectCompileFnUtils.scala:81)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Compile function returned partition key not compatible with the layer: Key('output,'seed-map,18939748)
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at com.here.platform.data.processing.driver.impl.executors.ExecutorUtils$.verifyPartitionKey(ExecutorUtils.scala:291)
    at com.here.platform.data.processing.driver.impl.executors.DirectCompileFnUtils$$anonfun$applyMappingFn$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DirectCompileFnUtils.scala:85)
    at com.here.platform.data.processing.driver.impl.executors.DirectCompileFnUtils$$anonfun$applyMappingFn$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DirectCompileFnUtils.scala:85)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at com.here.platform.data.processing.driver.impl.executors.DirectCompileFnUtils$$anonfun$applyMappingFn$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(DirectCompileFnUtils.scala:85)
    at com.here.platform.data.processing.driver.impl.executors.DirectCompileFnUtils$$anonfun$applyMappingFn$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(DirectCompileFnUtils.scala:83)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.here.platform.data.processing.exception.package$.wrapInTryWithContext(package.scala:100)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to the partition type of layer. Make sure the returned key has the correct `Partition.Name` type. If your layer is generically partitioned you have to build the partition name with `Generic()`, and not `HereTile()`.

Answer (score 0):

Also check Partition Type and Zoom level of layer.